# Laravel - How to declare a file path constent in .env file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

In one of my Laravel based application, I want to include a **JSON key file** that is currently located in **public/key/store.json**

Now I want to write a constant in Laravel **.env** file so that I can access that file anytime I want. So, I write the following line of code:

```
KEY_FILE='/public/key/store.json'
```

But it show file path does not exist.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my declaration?

Comment: The problem is probably that its trying to find it from the web route.  Have you tried to use it with base_path() helper?

Answer (score -1):

you should push your path in your app/config.php not in your .env

Comment: Elaborate on your answer please.